# Crystal Reports - security considerations when using with a .NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, security, crystal-reports

If a .NET web application utilizes Crystal Reports, are there any security considerations to make sure are covered?  For example, if someone has ad-hoc SQL queries (unrelated to Crystal Reports) in a web application, they should be sure to escape and quote strings that come in as user input if using them in the query.

Is there anything that should be done/reviewed for Crystal Reports to ensure proper security?